# Looping though childNodes and deleting all leaves one entry not deleted

Tags: javascript

I have a function that iterates all options returned from an API fetch, creates a `p` tag for each, and appends them all to a parent `div` called **options**

```
    textOptions.forEach((text) => {
        let newText = document.createElement('p')
        newText.innerHTML = text
        newText.addEventListener('click', () => {
            replaceSelectedText(newText.innerHTML, range)
            handleCloseMenu()
        })
        options.appendChild(newText)
    })
```

when the `handleCloseMenu()` function is executed, it is to check if the `div` **options** has any children and if so, remove them all, so that the next API call cacn return a fresh set of children.

```
const handleCloseMenu = () => {
    menu.style.display = 'none'
    if (options.hasChildNodes()) {
        options.childNodes.forEach((child) => {
            child.remove()
        })
    }
    console.log('OPTIONS CHILDREN', options.childNodes)
}
```

after the loop is done in my console.log I can see it has not deleted one of the children, it always leaves the second child. I also see it sitting there in my options during the next API call. Am I doing something incorrectly? I know I am of course but some info on what the problem is would be greatly appreciated

Comment: _“The read-only [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) property of the `Node` interface returns a **live** `NodeList` of child nodes of the given element […]. **Note**: The `NodeList` being live means that its content is changed each time new children are added or removed.”_

Answer (score 1):

`childNodes` is a live collection:

```js
options.childNodes.forEach((child) => {
  console.log('x');
  child.remove()
})
```

```html
<div id="options"><div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div><div>6</div></div>
```

If you remove an element contained in the collection, the collection will change *instantly* - while you're iterating over it, so indicies will be lost if you iterate 0-1-2-3 etc like normal.

Turn it into an array instead, to extract all values into a static collection first.

```
[...options.childNodes].forEach(
```